# Bandsawing a small log - how to keep the log on the bandsaw table?

Tags: safety, band-saw

I was trying to saw a small log (5" diameter) on a bandsaw, but was having a very difficult time keeping it flush on the table due to the irregularities in the log.

This question is different than "how to re-saw large logs" as I'm exclusively interested in bandsaw techniques and safety - not the broader aspect of re-sawing.

How could I have kept the log on the bandsaw table more effectively for both safety and quality of cut?

Comment: Bandsaw sled of some sort would be the answer as covered in this question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cut a 9"x9"x36" chunk of wood into boards?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-do-i-cut-a-9x9x36-chunk-of-wood-into-boards)

Comment: @Matt I see the similarity but that question doesn't ask specifically "how to keep a log on a bandsaw table?" I also didn't see mention of a bandsaw in the question either. But, the answer by Rob does look like a good solution to my specific question. I'm not sure what to do in that situation (as I didn't find this answer myself when I searched for my own question).

Comment: The question itself does not have to be a duplicate but I think you are asking a question which is resolved by the same answers. The answer suits your need which is why I flagged it. Others might not agree which is why the voting system exists. Robs answer was the one I wanted you to see. Could easily get more specific here.

Comment: Is there anyway to move Robs answer into this thread - or will it simply available in the form you presented above? I might have a hard time re-finding that answer if I don't remember to query the unrelated question. I will read more meta and usage stuff to get a grip on this.

Comment: @Matt possibly that re-framing of the question adds stand alone value.

Comment: @NipFu if you feel that the other answer is the best answer to your question, you could answer your own question below by paraphrasing and referencing that question, and then accept it as the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

Several times a year I rig my 14" bandsaw to resaw logs, usually up to 10" dia. and 4' long by removing the table from the saw and securing a 10' roller conveyor centered in place. (Sorry, I have no photos of it set up at this time).

[image: Roller conveyor]

I support the ends with 2x4 frames and bolt it to the saw table mounting brackets with some metal clips I made from scrap aluminum angles. The 10' length supports a 24" long sled (shown sitting on my table saw).  I rigged wheels to the sled to keep it on track. To mount the logs I simply screw them to the fence on the sled (be careful not to place the screws in the path of the bandsaw blade).  I also use wood blocks secured to the sled base and fence to keep logs from rocking. I whipped the sled up in a hurry so it has more play than I like which is most noticeable with logs longer than 4' where twist is possible.  I found that it helps if I start with a profile of a log with a flat bottom.  This increases the stability of the sled and log as it moves through the bandsaw.

[image: Resaw sled]

Comment: I thoroughly enjoyed this answer. I think I was looking for something a little "simpler"(?) though. The answer Matt references, Rob's answer, seemed more like what I was thinking of.